# Generate Dynamic Inputs with Unique Names & IDs

Tags: jquery, html, forms, dynamic

I am building a web form, within the form it's possible to add additional input boxes dynamically by clicking a button. I've got this part to work, however I need each input to have a unique `name` and `id`.

For example;

```
<input type="text" name="inventory_number[0]" id="inventory_number[0]">
<input type="text" name="inventory_number[1]" id="inventory_number[1]">
<input type="text" name="inventory_number[2]" id="inventory_number[2]">
```

Currently they all have the same `name` and `id`;

```
<input type="text" name="inventory_number[]" id="inventory_number[]">
<input type="text" name="inventory_number[]" id="inventory_number[]">
<input type="text" name="inventory_number[]" id="inventory_number[]">
```

My code is below along with a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/johnny_s/fq7z3jk9/). Any help is appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div class="control-group field_wrapper">
  <label class="control-label"><strong> Inventory Number 1</strong></label>
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="input-prepend">
      <input type="text" class="input-medium" name="inventory_number[]" id="inventory_number[]">
      <button class="btn btn-success add-number" type="button" title="Add MAC Address"><i class="icon-plus"></i> </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="additionalNumber"></div>
```

**JQuery**

```
var maxField = 10; 
var addButton = $('.add-number'); 
var wrapper = $('.additionalNumber'); 
var fieldHTML = '<div class="control-group field_wrapper"><label class="control-label"><strong> Inventory Number x</strong></label><div class="controls"><div class="input-prepend"><input type="text" class="input-medium"  name="inventory_number[]" id="inventory_number[]"><button class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button"><i class="icon-remove"></i> </button></div></div></div>';
var x = 1;
$(addButton).on('click', function(e) {
  if (x < maxField) {
    x++;
    $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML);
  }
  if (x >= maxField) {
    alert('Limited to 10.');
  }
});
$(wrapper).on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parents('.control-group').remove();
  x--; 
});
```

If there's an easier / more efficient way of achieving the above I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Why you need a different name? I think in your case the best solution is to use the array name convention like you does already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make fieldHtml a function and pass in `x`:

```js
//JQuery

var maxField = 10; 
var addButton = $('.add-number'); 
var wrapper = $('.additionalNumber'); 
function fieldHTML(inputNumber) {
    return `<div class="control-group field_wrapper"><label class="control-label"><strong> Inventory Number ${inputNumber}</strong></label><div class="controls"><div class="input-prepend"><input type="text" class="input-medium"  name="inventory_number[${inputNumber}]" id="inventory_number[${inputNumber}]"><button class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button"><i class="icon-remove"></i> Remove</button></div></div></div>`;
}
var x = 1;
$(addButton).on('click', function(e) {
  if (x < maxField) {
    x++;
    $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML(x));
  }
  if (x >= maxField) {
    alert('Limited to 10.');
  }
});
$(wrapper).on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parents('.control-group').remove();
  x--; 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="control-group field_wrapper">
  <label class="control-label"><strong> Inventory Number 1</strong></label>
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="input-prepend">
      <input type="text" class="input-medium" name="inventory_number[]" id="inventory_number[]">
      <button class="btn btn-success add-number" type="button" title="Add MAC Address"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="additionalNumber"></div>
```

Comment: post your fiddle link

Comment: version of jquery makes no difference here. i cant see any attempt in that fiddle link? Copy what i made above surely :)

Comment: Apologies, my fault! It works perfectly. I was using incorrect quotes in my `return` - I was using ' ' whereas I should be using ` ` - I didn't realise this made any difference?!

Comment: using backticks ``` is called a string template, and variables inside accessed with dollar/braces, like so: ` `some text and ${vars1}` `